# Why and in what cases we use $E$ instead of $\Delta E$ in energy-time uncertainity relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

sometimes in problems of energy or time uncertainity we use the value of energy of the particle/system to calculate the delta t. Now what are those cases specific examples, where we can apply this?

Comment: can you give an example or a link where this has been used?

Answer (score 0):

It never makes sense to use an absolute energy in this context. Absolute energies can differ by any arbitrary additive constant.